# Can't figure out how to get write access to work

Tags: nest-api

I'm talking to Nest Cloud API using Nodejs using firebase node module.  I'm using accessToken that I got from https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token, and this seems to work. My Nest user account got prompted to "accept" this request, which I did and my app is listed in the Nest Account "Works with Nest" page so all looks good.  I use this accessToken in call to authWithCustomToken and that works and my Nodejs application requested read/write permission (See https://developers.nest.com/products/978ea6e2-c301-4dff-8b38-f63d80757162).  And reading the Nest thermostat properties from https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/[deviceid] works, but when I try and write to hvac_mode like this:

> this.firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://developer-api.nest.com");
>
> this.myNestThermostat = this.firebaseRef.child("devices/thermostats/"+deviceId);
>
> this.myNestThermostat.set("{'hvac_mode': 'off'}", function (error) { ... }

and this always returns:

> FIREBASE WARNING: set at /devices/thermostats/fwxNBtjaok6KZJbSXhf2azuBmGSvkcjK failed: No write permission(s) for field(s): /devices/thermostats/fwxNBtjaok6KZJbSXhf2azuBmGSvkcjK

(where the deviceId is what I see when I enumerate my devices, I only have one, so I'm pretty sure it is correct).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, isn't that always the case, I found an answer already.  Turns out if I create a firebase reference to the property itself like this:

> var propertyRef = this.myNestThermostat.child(name);

Then the following succeeds:

> propertyRef.set(value, function (error) { ...

The firebase documentation was misleading on this because it led me to believe I could write this:

> this.myNestThermostat.set("{'hvac_mode': 'off'}", function (error) { ... }

which technically should have worked, but I guess that would mean I'd need write access on the whole of this.myNestThermostat, which I don't.  Tricky.

Anyway I'm happy because it works now, yay!  Firebase + nodejs rocks!